# Flot.js repetitive X axis values not showing

Tags: javascript, json, html, canvas, flot

I am using flot.js to display a graph. The following JSON is used to display the graph attached below.

```
{
    "data": [
        ["02:56", 50],
        ["06:56", 120],
        ["10:56", 170],
        ["14:56", 210],
        ["18:56", 260],
        ["22:56", 300],
        ["02:56", 380],
        ["06:56", 420],
        ["10:56", 460],
        ["14:56", 500],
        ["18:56", 570],
        ["22:56", 700]
    ]
}
```

Above JSON is for only blue color line. Note that X-axis time values 02:26, 06:26... up to six values are repeated second time.

[image]

The graph is only plotted for first six values. And When these values are repeated second time, the graph is drawn again from backwards. Would any body please tell me how to display all 12 X-axis points consequtively.

Comment: You don't want a 'back' line connected to the second `2:56`?

Comment: presently values are plotted like X-axis (2:56, 6:56, 10:56, 14:56, 18:56, 22:56 ) y-axis (0 to 190) and it conitnues plotting from y-axis (380 to 570) but here x-axis again starts from beginning (2:56, 6:56,...22:56).

But I need as follows:
(2:56, 6:56, 10:56, 14:56, 18:56, 22:56,2:56, 6:56, 10:56, 14:56, 18:56, 22:56) continuously in x-axis (12 continous values) in same single line.

Comment: So looks like two separate lines?

Comment: Yeah presently looks like 2 seperate lines. But i want in single line

Comment: The desired graph is: total 12 values should be on X-axis continuously (2:56, 6:56, 10:56, 14:56, 18:56, 22:56,2:56, 6:56, 10:56, 14:56, 18:56, 22:56). And that blue color line should be as a forward single line from left to right.

Comment: If the first 02:56 is not the same as the second 02:56 and so on, then add dates to make that clear.

Comment: Hi @Raidri.. I could use that. But no point of displaying date if the graph shows last 2 days of data. Obviously we know the date..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not a perfect solution. But Space is added at the end of repetitive time values. Here is the modified JSON. And it works fine.

```
{
    "data": [
        ["02:56", 50],
        ["06:56", 120],
        ["10:56", 170],
        ["14:56", 210],
        ["18:56", 260],
        ["22:56", 300],
        ["02:56 ", 380],
        ["06:56 ", 420],
        ["10:56 ", 460],
        ["14:56 ", 500],
        ["18:56 ", 570],
        ["22:56 ", 700]
    ]
}
```

Since I've added space, both values are not same. But It'll display same in the graph

Comment: I can't imagine what the final plot is using your solution. Can you post a screenshot somewhere?

Comment: And I read the doc of Flot, it said the data should be number not string. Is it OK to feed JSON string to the plot method, just curious.

Comment: I will edit the question soon with the details of desired graph picuture.. It has to be generated fully.. :)

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used Flot before, but I hope my suggestion may enlighten you.

Format your data as shown in this [Flot example](http://www.flotcharts.org/flot/examples/ajax/index.html) when dealing with JSON (check any [ see data ] link):

```
{
    "data": [[02:56, 50], [06:56, 120], [10:56, 170], ... ]
}
```

I guess you've known how to convert your time series to plot your graph, and the one more thing to do is to add `null` before the repeated time `2:56`. This trick is used to plot the red line in the [basic usage](http://www.flotcharts.org/flot/examples/basic-usage/).

```
{
    "data": [[02:56, 50], [06:56, 120], [10:56, 170], ..., null, [02:56, 380], [06:56, 420] ... ]
}
```

> If a null is specified as a point or if one of the coordinates is null
>   or couldn't be converted to a number, the point is ignored when
>   drawing. As a special case, a null value for lines is interpreted as a
>   line segment end, i.e. the points before and after the null value are
>   not connected. [Reference here.](https://github.com/flot/flot/blob/master/API.md#data-format)

Comment: Hi @Wang,
Thanks for the answer.. Using null is actually splitting the line into two. This should not occur in my case. But this trick is useful.